# change sqldatabase php script

Tags: php, mysql

i have this problem for 3 days already :(
i created a 3 databases via phpmyadmin
and i already put those 3 database into a dropdown list
what i wanted is, when ever i click submit, the default database changes dependin on the value of the dropdown list

this is the code i came up to

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form2" method="post" >
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><center><strong>Select Default Database</strong></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><center><select name="db_used">
<?php 
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";

$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
$result = mysql_list_dbs( $link );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ){
echo "<option>$row->Database</option>";
}
?>

</select></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>



 <?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name = "#this depends on the value of the dropdown list"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
?>
```

any help is greatly appreciated~~

Comment: What happens? Any error messages?

Comment: Use extreme caution here. The databases listed will be _everything_ the connected user (root!!) has access to, including `mysql, information_schema`.  Create a user which has access _only_ to the necessary databases.

Comment: Your value from the `<select>` is in `$_POST['db_used']`  It is _very highly recommended_ to create a whitelist of possible databases to connect to, rather than allow connecting to _any_ available database (which will include `information_schema, test`, others)

Comment: @Znarkus mycode doesnt work, i tried making a variable like $db_name = "$dropdownlistvalue"

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski sorry im still a newbie, how can i do that? >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this will help you.You can do it as:

**create index.php**

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form2" method="post" action='generate.php'>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><center><strong>Select Default Database</strong></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><center><select name="db_used">
<?php 
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";

$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
$result = mysql_list_dbs( $link );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ){
echo "<option>$row->Database</option>";
}
?>

</select></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Crate generate.php**

```
<?php
$HOMEDIR = getcwd() . "/";
# /home/virtual/magicplugin.com/var/www/html/
$TEMPLATEDIR = $HOMEDIR . "";

$fName = $TEMPLATEDIR . "dbConnection.php";
    $fh = fopen($fName, "r");   $fContents = fread($fh, filesize($fName));  fclose($fh);
    $fContents = str_replace("__databaseName__",$_REQUEST['db_used'],$fContents);
    $outFile ="index.php";
    $fp = fopen($outFile,"w");
        fwrite($fp,$fContents); fclose($fp);

        echo"Connection generated.Please Check";
        ?>
```

**Create dbConnection.php**

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form2" method="post" action='generate.php'>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><center><strong>Select Default Database</strong></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><center><select name="db_used">
<?php 
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";

$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
$result = mysql_list_dbs( $link );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ){
echo "<option>$row->Database</option>";
}
?>

</select></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>



 <?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name = "__databaseName__"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
?>
```

Comment: if it is so you can accept the answer..by checking the button right.